# Did I minimize the cost correctly?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a word problem that reads as so

*A farmer wants to fence a rectangular part of his land (30,000 square feet). The fenced area is to have one border shared with a neighbor which he wishes to be fancy so he will spend 25 dollars per linear foot on that side where as he will use 5 dollars per linear foot of fencing on the rest. Find the dimensions that will minimize the cost*

**I set up my equations (x shares the border with the fancy fence)**

$ A = xy $

$ C = 25x + 5(x + 2y)   = 30x + 10y $

**Then I found my x-value**

$ x = \frac{30,000}{y} $

**Plugged it in**

$ C = 30(\frac{30,000}{y}) + 10y  = \frac{900,000}{y} + 10y $

**Derivative of C**

$ C' = \frac{900,000}{y^2} + 10 $

$ -900,000 = -10y^2  $

$ y^2 = 90,000 $

$ y = 300 $

**Finally, plugged it into original equation**

$ 30,000 = 300x = x = 100 $

I just wanted to check if I've done this right. If not, can you explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: The answer is numerically correct. You did not show how you got it. And the line $ C = 30(\frac{30,000}{y}) + 10y   = 90,000 = y^2   =  y = 300 $ is really bad, $C$ is not $90,000$, nor is $y^2$ equal to $y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I fixed it, it was a formatting issue that I didn't spot as I posted it. Fixed it with new lines for each step.

Comment: Should say you are setting $C'=0$. As I mentioned before, the dimensions you obtained are correct. For completeness, should explain why this gives minimum cost. In many calculus courses, solution would be marked correct without such justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

> $C = 30(\frac{30,000}{y}) + 10y   = 90,000 = y^2   =  y = 300$

Take a good look at that: it says (among other things) that $90,000=300$. Do you really want to say that?

Note too that you’re trying to find an extreme value of something, so you should expect to take a derivative of something.

What you should get from $C=30\left(\frac{30,000}y\right)+10y$ is that $C=\frac{900,000}y+10y$. Now you want to find the value of $y$ that minimizes $C$, so you calculate $\frac{dC}{dy}$, set it to $0$, and solve for critical points. We have

$$\frac{dC}{dy}=-\frac{900,000}{y^2}+10\;,$$

so we set $$-\frac{900,000}{y^2}+10=0$$ and solve: $10y^2=900,000$, $y^2=90,000$, and $y=300$. You still have to check that this critical value yields a minimum of $C$, but that’s easy to do: by inspection $\frac{dC}{dy}$ is negative when $y$ is a little less than $300$ and positive when $y$ is greater than $300$.

Comment: Sorry it was a formatting issue that I fixed by line separations. It should have read `-> 90,000 = y^2 -> y = 300`. So the dimensions I have are correct, and the overall cost of the fence would be $6000?

Comment: $C=\text{whatever}$ does not imply that $90,00=y^2$.

Comment: @StrugglingWithMath: What you now have is correct, apart from not including a verification that you’ve actually found the **minimum** cost, but the original version can’t be saved by turning some of the equals signs into implications, because in it you never took a derivative and had no way to conclude that $y^2=90,000$.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to explicitly say $x$ is the side shared with the neighbor and $y$ is the other direction.  Under "Plugged it in" your equal signs are not all equal.  You should have $C=\frac {900,000}y + 10y$, but this is not $90,000, y^2$ or $y$.  Now take the derivative with respect to $y$, set it to $0, \ldots$

Comment: My issue was I should have put arrows instead of equal signs. I separated each step into new lines instead. Does that look better?